# Bootable pen drive 16.04 is not able to recognize by my laptop(UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I am using ubuntu 14.04 in my desktop and now i want to upgrade it to 16.04 so i downloaded ubuntu 16.04 image file and i make my pen drive to bootable by using Startup Disk Creator available in ubuntu and then i tried to boot from pen drive but it is not being recognized by the computer, by this i compared the files of 14.04 and 16.04 files and then i found that 'autorun.ini' and 'wubi' files are missing. so can anyone tell me 
1.What to do to be recognized? and 
2.Can we create those missing files manually?
Thank you

Comment: Those files are related to installing in Windows in a way that's no longer supported. If you're trying to install in that way (a [WUBI install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)), I recommend you reconsider. If you're trying to install in a more conventional dual-boot configuration, chances are you need to prepare the boot medium in another way -- say, using Rufus or UNetbootin rather than Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: A [community supported Wubi](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) provides a wubi.exe for 16.04. see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info). But if you don't want a Wubi install, you don't need a wubi.exe

Answer (score 0):

Please don't upgrade to 16.04 right now, as there is a bug issue, regarding installation of third party softwares.wait until they debug the said issue.Till then keep enjoying 14.04.

Comment: You could maybe add sources for the different statements you did.